# .Net XML Documentation Standard

Tags: .net, documentation

I have looked at the Suggested related questions but none of them are what I am looking for.  As a new developer I am trying hard to follow best practices and documentation is a big one.  As I go I am trying to create XML docs in my code.  I discovered the [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) plug in which helps speed this up.

My question though is; Is there a commonly excepted standard as to what should be included in the XML.  By default I am using `<Summary><Param><Returns>` when applicable.  Are there others?  Should I include author?  How? `<Patrick></Patrick>`?  Is `<Remarks>` worth the time?

I would be grateful for any guidance on this.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only recently found [this guide to XML documentation](http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html). It's *really* handy. It's not a best practice guide as such, but it's good at covering the tags which aren't used very often and thus get forgotten.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, it's annoying - other than the Google cache, I don't know of any other sites with the same content :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet: No cache any more... :S Any other useful guide out there?

Comment: Here it is via the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20090604112954/http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html

Comment: @Porges: Thanks - I may try to contact the author and resurrect the page somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I definitely think the `<remarks>` tag is worth the time, as it allows you to elaborate on the summary, and more knowledge is always a good thing.

I also think that the `<typeparamref>` is important for generic classes.

Inside each of your elements, you should also make use of the `<see>` tag as well, so that you can link documentation together.

Outside of the standard tags, I add `<author>` to show the original author of the class/method/property/etc, etc as well as a `<created>` tag to indicate when the member was created.  In a team environment, you will probably want something more robust, like so:

```
<revisions>
  <revision>
    <author>Nicholas Paldino</author>
    <revised>2009-02-01</revised>
  </revision>
  <revision>
    <author>Mr_Mom</author>
    <revised>2009-02-11</revised>
  </revision>
</revisions>
```

Comment: @casperOne: I think I'd find all of that getting in the way. That's what source control's there for... it's much more likely to be consistent and accurate, and doesn't clutter the code.